# How can I finish compiling webpack early without affecting the next compilation?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I want some files in a specific directory in a specific period of time when the change does not trigger compilation, and the next time other files change can combine the two changes to trigger compilation, who can teach me how to do this? By the way, I am a Vue2.x project and the configuration is basically written in vue.config.js. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.